# Logistic Regression with dummy variables?

Tags: logistic, multicollinearity, categorical-encoding, intercept

I am working on a problem where response variable is binary and my features are dummy variables. I observed when I include intercept to model all the dummy variables' p-values are equal to 1. When I remove constant p-values seems ok. My question is should not we include intercept when we have dummy variables as our **only features**? If it is so, what is the reason for that?

Another follow up question is about perfect multi-colinearity, I remember from linear regression, if we do not drop one of our dummy variables we cannot invert the matrix due to multi-colinearity thus we cannot get our coefficients. I know logistic regression coef. found through MLE but I wonder if multi-colinearity still causes different issues in this case?

Comment: Logistic regression with dummy variables is equivalent to linear discriminant analysis. Inversion of the cross-products matrix with an intercept and dummies spanning all of the possible combinations is not about *multicollinearity*. It's about complete or quasi-complete separation, a data problem that will cause maximum likelihood estimation convergence to fail. Paul Allison explains this well here, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228813245_

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131456/confused-about-0-intercept-in-logistic-regression-in-r https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430906/interpreting-intercept-in-logistic-regression-with-binary-variable-in-r https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154404/fitting-a-logistic-regression-without-an-intercept https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230839/interpreting-intercept-in-logistic-regression-when-there-is-more-than-one-catego, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215779/removing-intercept-from-glm-for-multiple-factorial-predictors-only-works-for-fir/218034#218034